# Elisp, calling with progn yields different result than calling individually

Tags: elisp

In Emacs (with `C-:`), those 2 calls yield different results :

```
(progn (run-python (python-shell-parse-command) nil nil) (python-shell-send-buffer))
```

and

```
(run-python (python-shell-parse-command) nil nil)
# then, in another C-:
(python-shell-send-buffer)
```

In the first call, I get a python shell with the following error:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__PYTHON_EL_eval' is not defined
```

Why is the result different for these 2 elisp codes? I am trying to put these commands in a function, but I cannot if they yield an error together.

Comment: My *guess* is that the second function is called with a different *current buffer*. Emacs could change current buffer between calls, e.g. when a function selects a different window to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Lindydancer, `run-python` selects the comint buffer, so `python-shell-send-buffer` will be called with *that* as the current buffer, which probably isn't what you intended.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `save-current-buffer`

Also note that the inferior process is started asynchronously, so `run-python` *might* return before the process is ready to receive input.  You may or may not have to take that into account.

---

*In general* there is no reason to expect running two things in immediate sequence via `progn` to produce the same results as two completely independent calls to each of those things, separated by not only time but also by trips through the Emacs command loop, with all of the intervening executed code which that entails.

Comment: You are right! Adding `(sleep-for 2)` after `run-python` and using `save-current-buffer` work.